# How to add multiple levels of sorting in yii2 controller as default sort

Tags: php, sorting, yii2

i want to sort 3 levels or ads.The first level is premium (status=2) then featured(status=1) and regular(status=0).In the list view i need to show the premium ads first with sort data desc.Means latest post in the premium ads first.Then i want to show the featured ads also like latest post first,Then the regular ads also like latest post first.
And i have a default sort like

```
$dataProvider = $searchModel->search($params);
$defaultSort = $dataProvider->getSort();
$defaultSort->defaultOrder = ['date'=>SORT_DESC];
```

This code will sort the entire listing with the date sort_desc order.Not filtering premium , featured and regular wise.so i changed this to

```
$defaultSort->defaultOrder = ['status' => SORT_DESC,'date'=>SORT_DESC];
```

But nothing happened.How can i do this 3 level sorting in yii2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be

```
$dataProvider = $searchModel->search($params);
$dataProvider->sort->defaultOrder =  ['status' => SORT_DESC,'date'=>SORT_DESC];
```

Comment: @scaisEdge Actually you're wrong. `getSort()` returns instance of `Sort`, and any change on this object will affect every place where this instance is referenced (including `BaseDataProvider::$_sort`) - this is how objects works in PHP. I'm surprised that this answer is accepted, since your example is logically identical to the code sample from question.